# Magento Local Block Won't Override

Tags: php, xml, magento

I am trying to override a plugin in the local code pool with another plugin in the local code pool, but the block I need to override is not overriding. The helper in my config xml overrode just fine. Any, ideas on what my issue might be?

I also used Modules Conflict Detector and made sure we do not have any conflicts in our magento instance.

**Module I am trying to override**

*app/code/local/Idev/OneStepCheckout/etc/config.xml*

```
<blocks>
    <onestepcheckout>
        <class>Idev_OneStepCheckout_Block</class>
    </onestepcheckout>
</blocks>
```

*app/code/local/Idev/OneStepCheckout/Block/Checkout.php*

```
class Idev_OneStepCheckout_Block_Checkout extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Abstract  {
    public function getBillingFieldsOrder($fields = array()){
    ....
    }
}
```

**My Module**

*app/etc/modules/KNG_OneStepCheckout.xml*

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <KNG_OneStepCheckout>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Idev_OneStepCheckout />
            </depends>
        </KNG_OneStepCheckout>
    </modules>
</config>
```

*app/code/local/KNG/OneStepCheckout/etc/config.xml*

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <onestepcheckout>
            <rewrite>
                <checkout>KNG_OneStepCheckout_Block_Checkout</checkout>
            </rewrite>
        </onestepcheckout>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <onestepcheckout>
            <rewrite>
                <checkout>KNG_OneStepCheckout_Helper_Checkout</checkout>
            </rewrite>
        </onestepcheckout>
    </helpers>
</global>
```

*app/code/local/KNG/OneStepCheckout/Block/Checkout.php*

```
class KNG_OneStepCheckout_Block_Checkout extends Idev_OneStepCheckout_Block_Checkout {
    public function getBillingFieldsOrder($fields = array()) {
    ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that their module already had another class overriding the class I was trying to override. Not sure why it didn't show up as a conflict when I checked for conflicts though.

**Their Class that was overriding already**

*app/code/local/Idev/OneStepCheckout/Block/Fields.php*

```
class Idev_OneStepCheckout_Block_Fields extends Idev_OneStepCheckout_Block_Checkout
{
....
}
```

To make my override work I just overrode the fields class instead of the checkout class and it worked like a charm.

**Working Code**

*app/etc/modules/KNG_OneStepCheckout.xml*

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <KNG_OneStepCheckout>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Idev_OneStepCheckout />
            </depends>
        </KNG_OneStepCheckout>
    </modules>
</config>
```

*app/code/local/KNG/OneStepCheckout/etc/config.xml*

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <onestepcheckout>
            <rewrite>
                <fields>KNG_OneStepCheckout_Block_Fields</fields>
            </rewrite>
        </onestepcheckout>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <onestepcheckout>
            <rewrite>
                <checkout>KNG_OneStepCheckout_Helper_Checkout</checkout>
            </rewrite>
        </onestepcheckout>
    </helpers>
</global>
```

*app/code/local/KNG/OneStepCheckout/Block/Fields.php*

```
class KNG_OneStepCheckout_Block_Fields extends Idev_OneStepCheckout_Block_Fields {
    public function getBillingFieldsOrder($fields = array()) {
    ....
    }
}
```